# Write init method to pass model to view controller before viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I not familiar with storyboards, i have superclass for UIViewController, that have init method like that:

```
 convenience init(viewModel: Any){
        self.init()
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
```

So, when `viewDidLoad` is called, i already have viewModel that is not nil.

And i can easy create view controller with model like that:

```
let pvc = ProductViewController(viewModel: pvm)
self.navController?.pushViewController(pvc, animated: true)
```

How to add this capability to storyboards? What i want is, pass model to constructor, to be sure that when viewDidLoad is called model is exist.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the model before `viewDidLoad`? I understand that in macOS where Cocoa Bindings expect values right after the initialization. But what functionality in iOS requires valid values before `viewDidLoad`? Isn't a shared class (singleton) an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this with storyboards as view controllers are initialized beforehand.

I wrote a [post](https://medium.com/@shanev/view-model-specialized-view-controllers-using-storyboards-in-swift-88169d2b43c7) on making view controller and view model associations more explicit though.

Comment: your solution is great!